# Spring boot, Kotlin, Kafka and shutdown

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I have a Spring boot / Kotlin application that has a Kafka listener embedded. I am programmatically shutting it down at some point by calling:

```
configurableApplicationContext.close()
```

However, Kafka listener does not shut down at that time and instead I get this:

```
Failed to shut down 1 bean with phase value 2147483547 within timeout of 30000: [org.springframework.kafka.config.internalKafkaListenerEndpointRegistry]
```

After that, the app shuts down as expected.

What do I need to do differently so it shuts down cleanly when requested?

Comment: Why are you trying to shutdown your consumer in your application code? Spring should do this for you when your app exits.

Comment: What version are you using? There was a problem once when there were no `@KafkaListener` s to `stop()`. If that's not it, show your code and configuration together with a DEBUG log of the shutdown process.

Comment: @chrsblck The app is basically a kafka listener. It would never exit on its own. So basically this is a "I've processed enough, let's stop" thing.

Comment: @levantpied got it, makes sense. I think Gary Russell's question and suggestion is worth considering.

Comment: I had the same issue with `2.3.9.RELEASE`. If I explicitly inject `KafkaListenerEndpointRegistry registry` and call `registry.stop();` before the shutdown it shuts down gracefully after 10s.