# How to retry consuming message, then stop consuming, when error occurs in listener

Tags: spring, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I have Kafka listener writing data to a database, in case of database timeout (JdbcException), I'd like to retry, and if timeouts persist, stop consuming Kafka message.

As far as I understand, Spring Kafka 2.9 has 2 `CommonErrorHandler` implementations:

- [DefaultErrorHandler](https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/api/org/springframework/kafka/listener/DefaultErrorHandler.html) tries to redeliver messages several times and then send failed messages to logs or DLQ
- [CommonContainerStoppingErrorHandler](https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/api/org/springframework/kafka/listener/CommonContainerStoppingErrorHandler.html) stops listener container and message consumption

I would like to chain both of them: first try to redeliver messages several times, then stop container when delivery doesn't succeed.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `DefaultErrorHandler` with a custom recoverer that calls a `CommonContainerStoppingErrorHandler` after the retries are exhausted.

See this answer for an example

[How do you exit spring boot application programmatically when retries are exhausted, to prevent kafka offset commit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67076203/how-do-you-exit-spring-boot-application-programmatically-when-retries-are-exhaus/67077461#67077461)

(It uses the older `SeekToCurrentErrorHandler`, but the same concept applies.)

Comment: The idea is to wrap a CommonContainerStoppingErrorHandler  in a ConsumerRecordRecoverer, is it? The CommonContainerStoppingErrorHandler.handleOne/handleBatch methods take a Consumer in their signature, how do I get this Consumer instance? How to implement properly for a Batch listener?

Comment: The consumer is not used in that error handler; or you can simply copy the code from its `stopContainer()` method. Batch is a bit more complicated because (unless you throw a `BatchListenerFailedException` to indicate which record in the batch failed) the recoverer is called for all records in the batch.