# How to invoke CommonContainerStoppingErrorHandler once retries are exhausted with Batch listener

Tags: spring-boot, kafka-consumer-api, spring-kafka, spring-cloud-stream

I am using spring boot (version 2.7.1) with spring cloud stream kafka binder (2.8.5) for processing Kafka messages

I've functional style consumer that consumes messages in batches. Right now its retrying 10 times and commits the offset for errored records.

I want now to introduce the mechanism of retry for certain numbers (works using below error handler) then stop processing messages and fail entire batch messages without auto committing offset.

I read through the documents and understand that `CommonContainerStoppingErrorHandler` can be used for stopping the container from consuming messages.

My handler looks below now and its retries exponentially.

```
@Bean
    public ListenerContainerCustomizer<AbstractMessageListenerContainer<String, Message>> errorHandler() {
        return (container, destinationName, group) -> {
            container.getContainerProperties().setAckMode(ContainerProperties.AckMode.BATCH);
            ExponentialBackOffWithMaxRetries backOffWithMaxRetries = new ExponentialBackOffWithMaxRetries(2);
            backOffWithMaxRetries.setInitialInterval(1);
            backOffWithMaxRetries.setMultiplier(2.0);
            backOffWithMaxRetries.setMaxInterval(5);
            container.setCommonErrorHandler(new DefaultErrorHandler(backOffWithMaxRetries));
        };
}
```

1. How do I chain `CommonContainerStoppingErrorHandler` along with above error handler, so the failed batch is not commited and replayed upon restart ?
2. with `BatchListenerFailedException` from consumer, it is possible to fail entire batch (including one or other valid records before any problematic record in that batch) ?

Answer (score 0):

1. Add a custom recoverer to the error handler - see this answer for an example: [How do you exit spring boot application programmatically when retries are exhausted, to prevent kafka offset commit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67076203/how-do-you-exit-spring-boot-application-programmatically-when-retries-are-exhaus/67077461#67077461)
2. No; records before the failed one will have their offsets committed.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Reg. 2nd point, Can i use Manual Ack to commit the batch at once all records processed ?

Comment: You could, but it's not really necessary, the container will take care of it (and it's a different question to the one you asked). Throw any other exception and the whole batch will be retried (and sent to the recoverer after retries are exhausted).