# Backoff none exhausted for "topic"

Tags: spring-kafka

That's how I configure the exception handler and thought it would be an infinite retry.

```
@Bean
fun commonErrorHandler() = DefaultErrorHandler(
    ExponentialBackOff(2000, 1.1).apply {
        maxInterval = 60 * 1000 // 1 minutes
    } // 2000, 2000 * 1.1, 2000 * 1.1 * 1.1 ...
)


org.springframework.kafka.listener.ListenerExecutionFailedException: Listener failed; 
nested exception is 
org.springframework.messaging.converter.MessageConversionException: Could not read 
JSON:
```

But with an incompatible message, the retrays stopped and when raising the service with a new payload, the message was not read. Has offset shifted? What kind of behavior should I expect for such an error? Destroying a thread in a container?

I use spring boot auto - configure. Default AckMode = RECORD. Tell me what happened? :(

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear what you are saying, but certain exceptions (such as `MessageConversionException`) are considered fatal (by default) and not retryable.

If a record can't be converted then it doesn't matter how many times you try, it will continue to be that way.

You can change the default behavior by setting various properties.

```java
/**
 * Set an exception classifications to determine whether the exception should cause a retry
 * (until exhaustion) or not. If not, we go straight to the recoverer. By default,
 * the following exceptions will not be retried:
 * <ul>
 * <li>{@link DeserializationException}</li>
 * <li>{@link MessageConversionException}</li>
 * <li>{@link MethodArgumentResolutionException}</li>
 * <li>{@link NoSuchMethodException}</li>
 * <li>{@link ClassCastException}</li>
 * </ul>
 * All others will be retried.
 * When calling this method, the defaults will not be applied.
 * @param classifications the classifications.
 * @param defaultValue whether or not to retry non-matching exceptions.
 * @see BinaryExceptionClassifier#BinaryExceptionClassifier(Map, boolean)
 * @see #addNotRetryableExceptions(Class...)
 */
public void setClassifications(Map<Class<? extends Throwable>, Boolean> classifications, boolean defaultValue) {
    Assert.notNull(classifications, "'classifications' + cannot be null");
    this.classifier = new ExtendedBinaryExceptionClassifier(classifications, defaultValue);
}

/**
 * Add exception types to the default list. By default, the following exceptions will
 * not be retried:
 * <ul>
 * <li>{@link DeserializationException}</li>
 * <li>{@link MessageConversionException}</li>
 * <li>{@link ConversionException}</li>
 * <li>{@link MethodArgumentResolutionException}</li>
 * <li>{@link NoSuchMethodException}</li>
 * <li>{@link ClassCastException}</li>
 * </ul>
 * All others will be retried, unless {@link #defaultFalse()} has been called.
 * @param exceptionTypes the exception types.
 * @see #removeClassification(Class)
 * @see #setClassifications(Map, boolean)
 */
@SafeVarargs
@SuppressWarnings("varargs")
public final void addNotRetryableExceptions(Class<? extends Exception>... exceptionTypes) {
    add(false, exceptionTypes);
}

/**
 * Add exception types that can be retried. Call this after {@link #defaultFalse()} to
 * specify those exception types that should be classified as true.
 * All others will be retried, unless {@link #defaultFalse()} has been called.
 * @param exceptionTypes the exception types.
 * @since 2.8.4
 * @see #removeClassification(Class)
 * @see #setClassifications(Map, boolean)
 */
@SafeVarargs
@SuppressWarnings("varargs")
public final void addRetryableExceptions(Class<? extends Exception>... exceptionTypes) {
    add(true, exceptionTypes);
}

/**
 * Remove an exception type from the configured list. By default, the following
 * exceptions will not be retried:
 * <ul>
 * <li>{@link DeserializationException}</li>
 * <li>{@link MessageConversionException}</li>
 * <li>{@link ConversionException}</li>
 * <li>{@link MethodArgumentResolutionException}</li>
 * <li>{@link NoSuchMethodException}</li>
 * <li>{@link ClassCastException}</li>
 * </ul>
 * All others will be retried, unless {@link #defaultFalse()} has been called.
 * @param exceptionType the exception type.
 * @return the classification of the exception if removal was successful;
 * null otherwise.
 * @since 2.8.4
 * @see #addNotRetryableExceptions(Class...)
 * @see #setClassifications(Map, boolean)
 */
@Nullable
public Boolean removeClassification(Class<? extends Exception> exceptionType) {
    return this.classifier.getClassified().remove(exceptionType);
}

/**
 * By default, unmatched types classify as true. Call this method to make the default
 * false, and remove types explicitly classified as false. This should be called before
 * calling any of the classification modification methods.
 * @since 2.8.4
 */
public void defaultFalse() {
    this.classifier = new ExtendedBinaryExceptionClassifier(new HashMap<>(), false);
}
```

Comment: Okey, the problem is that when I corrected the error in my code (changed the payload), the message was not read again. Is it true that in this case we shifted the offset?

Comment: Yes; the offset is committed for when a record exhausts retries and is sent to the recoverer. As I said, you can change that default behavior.

Comment: Also see this answer for how to stop the container, instead, when retries fail https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67076203/how-do-you-exit-spring-boot-application-programmatically-when-retries-are-exhaus/67077461#67077461 (just use `DefaultErrorHandler` which supersedes the `SeekToCurrentErrorHandler` there.

Comment: So I used DefaultErrorHandler

    @Bean
    fun commonErrorHandler() = DefaultErrorHandler(
        ExponentialBackOff(2000, 1.1).apply {
            maxInterval = 60 * 1000 // 1 minutes
        } // 2000, 2000 * 1.1, 2000 * 1.1 * 1.1 ...
    )

Comment: Yes, this error is incorrigible. But I am making a new release of the service with a fixed DTO. And I want to read this message again

Comment: You can either do what I suggested (stop the container when the exception cannot be retried, in which case the offset won't be committed), or use the seek capabilities to reset the offset so that the record is refetched.

Comment: You can either do what I suggested (stop the container when the exception cannot be retried, in which case the offset won't be committed), or use the seek capabilities to reset the offset so that the record is refetched.